# Guava ListenableFuture failure finding the source object

Tags: java, guava

When using Guava's ListenableFuture how does one know the task that failed.
Example

```
FutureCallback<AsyncHTTPResponse> future = new FutureCallback<AsyncHTTPResponse>() {
  @Override
  public void onFailure(Throwable arg0)
  {
     // In this block I do not know who succeeded. We could create custom 
     // exceptions and put the object in there, but what if we are not
     // directly causing the exception. Seems like there should be an easy
     // way to get the callable task that failed to produce a success result
  }

  @Override
  public void onSuccess(AsyncHTTPResponse arg0)
  {
    // In this block I know the original object that succeded
  }
};
```

So in this example I cannot find the callable that was given a URL to try to get some data over http. Thus the failure does not know which URL has failed. Sure there are workarounds like recording futures and urls in tables but is there a cleaner way to use the framework to do this for you?

Comment: cant you use this.getURL ?

Comment: This is a Future, not my class

Answer (score 0):

The solution I usually see is to create a new callback instance for each request:

```
final URL url = ...;
ListenableFuture<AsyncHTTPResponse> future = makeRequest(url);
addCallback(future, new FutureCallback<AsyncHTTPResponse>() {
  @Override
  public void onFailure(Throwable e)
  {
    // do something with url
  }

  ...
});
```